# YAML, Specifying a fully qualified Azure task version

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to use the `AzureRMWebAppDeployment@4` azure task, but in the newest code there is a bug where it is not updating the Azure Deployment Centre with the correct version numbers.

So, I am trying to use `- task: AzureRMWebAppDeployment@4.198.0` in yaml to select a known task version that does this updating of the Deployment Center.

My issue is, it is not selecting the minor version of the task, it is always using version 4.205.13.

In Microsofts documentation it states that the minor version can be specified.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/tasks?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#task-versions

Is there something I am not specifying?

CODE:

````
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- checkout: none

- task: AzureRMWebAppDeployment@4.198.0
  inputs:
    appType: webApp
    ConnectedServiceName: '[SUB]'
    WebAppName: '[NAME]'
    Package: $(PIPELINE.WORKSPACE)/Build/drop/**/*.zip```
````

Answer (score 0):

> YAML, Specifying a fully qualified Azure task version

I could specify full version number of a task with old verison, like `4.1.10`:

[image]

If you did not use it, please share your YAML file and how did you use it in terraform.

As workaround, you could try to use the `AzureRMWebAppDeployment@3` task.

Comment: This a baisc YAML script that I am using to test this has been added to the main question.